# Set default value to a new column of a property, mongoose query

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using node express in a project. I am getting or setting data like 
    
      `Service.find({ $and: 
                [{ name: req.body.service }, 
                 { order: req.body.order }] 
             })`

Now I want to add a column in the same table and set a default value. For example, in service table I want to add a column 'deleted' and set it to false for all the current rows. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the column in your model definition and set the default value.

```
columnName : {
    type : String,
    default : 'Abcd'
},
//  For your case
isDeleted : {
    type : Boolean,
    default : false
},
```